# iOS: UIwebview from dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios-frameworks

I am creating an ios dynamic framework that contains a UIWebView, when added to an ios app, should run this UIWebView on the app.

To do so, I have a ***framework*** already created and it has -

- Storyboard.storyboard
- ViewController.swift

In the Storyboard, I added a **View Controller** and tagged it to ViewController.swift. Added a **Web View** to the **View Controller** and named it as loginWebView

In The viewcontroller, I have -

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

public class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate     {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginWebView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var MyLabel: UILabel!


    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let webViewUrl = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.com")


        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: webViewUrl! as URL)
        loginWebView.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest)
        loginWebView.delegate = self


    }

    override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

What I need now is to add this framework in an iOS App, and I already added this framework in a sample app. After adding the framework, in a ViewController, I am doing below to get the Framework's storyboard in the app

```
        let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "be.colruyt.SampleLogin")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: frameworkBundle)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        print(vc)  //Print gives "SampleLogin.ViewController"
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I run the app, the Storyboard is loaded, ViewController is loaded but nothing happens on the UIWebView.

What is missing here? Is the approach correct? Need Help.